# Cassandra select query using IN command in map field

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I have created a table 'test', and inserted some values using below commands using CQL .

`create table testt(val map<text,text>, id text primary key);
 insert into testt (val,id) values ({'key':'1'},'1');`

When I retrieve using below query it works

`select * from testt where val['key']='1' allow filtering;`

I need to retrieve multiple values which all contains the value in val[
key']. Using below command throwing error.

`select * from testt where val['key'] IN( '1' ) allow filtering;`

`SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:37 no viable alternative at input 'IN' (... testt where val['key'] [IN]...)">`

Is there any other way or methods available to get that desired output?

Comment: Hello. What is the need ? Search on collection is very complex. You can probably use an other model to search desired value more easily. For example use a search table.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can retrieve values for multiple keys in Cassandra is by doing multiple queries.  You may be able to adjust your Primary Key to accommodate for getting the values you want with a single query.